# Flask - First Step Issue (Windows)

Tags: python, flask

I've just started with coding. I've followed few tutorials before, but now building Flask app. I've started with the most basic code and I'm not getting results I need. It seems previous project results are still appearing on a server:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000, and Hello World shows on the second server.

Any thoughts how to delink first project?

Thanks.

Code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"


if __name__== '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Result:

```
* Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.1.232:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 246-654-290
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What do you mean by "It seems previous project results are still appearing on a server"? What is the "second server"?

Comment: Press CTRL+C to quit

Comment: Thanks, problem is that previous project is showing on link: "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000". How do I delink it from current project?

Answer (score 1):

To stop running the application, you just need to `Press CTRL+C to quit`.

You will see this in the CMD prompt (or the inbuilt terminal in `vscode` in my example case) below.

[image]